# $_POST['id'] php?id= not working

Tags: php, post, http-post

As I understand a php POST method can be passed through the url

File name: test.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['id']{
     echo'Great';
}else{
     echo'Why ?';
 }

 ?>
```

When I put manually in the browser /test.php?id=value it always returns the else statement

Why ?

Comment: caue your doing a get request not a post

Comment: Because if you do it in the browser-URL it is a `$_GET['id']`.

Comment: Regardless whether you make a POST or a GET request, query variables added to the url will be available in `$_GET` and not `$_POST`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, really appreciate it
How would I tell the browser to make a POST request ?

Comment: You post a form (with the correct method set...) for example or you use javascript to make a POST request.

Comment: all parameters that are puts in the URL like you have done are retrieved by using the `$_GET` global variable, and in you case you must use `isset($_GET['id']`) as the condition instead of what you have put in you if condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `test.php?id=value` in the browser is a GET method, not POST.

You can always get the value with $_GET

Answer (score 2):

Because, below line of code is equivalent to `GET` method not `POST`

```
 /test.php?id=value
```

And, since `$_POST['id']` value was not set, it will return `false`. You need to check `isset($_GET['id'])` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want make secure, use `$_REQUEST['id']`

This works for GET and POST